# Dropdown menu not working *SIGH* Firebase database

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code that does not populate the dropdown menu like it should ,

the code should pull the data from the firebase and populate the dropdown menu however when clicking on the select fleet number box nothing happens

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Fleet Management Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Fleet Management Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fleet-dropdown">
            <label for="fleetSelect">Select Fleet Number:</label>
            <select id="fleetSelect"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="vehicle-details" id="vehicleInfo">
            <h2>Vehicle Details</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="notifications">
            <h2>Notifications</h2>
            <ul id="notificationList"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const fleetSelect = document.getElementById("fleetSelect");
const vehicleInfo = document.getElementById("vehicleInfo");
const notificationList = document.getElementById("notificationList");

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA5UBOjIXF09BZJrF8ngFG-ciFuNy-C6r8",
    authDomain: "trucktrackpro.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "trucktrackpro",
    storageBucket: "trucktrackpro.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "988041977411",
    appId: "1:988041977411:web:6fc1a7980ecf0c39043ef6"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const database = firebase.database();

const SERVICE_INTERVALS = {
    M1: [40000, 120000, 200000],
    M2: [80000, 160000, 320000],
    M3: [240000, 480000],
};

const PART_REPLACEMENT_INTERVALS = {
    PartA: 50000,
    PartB: 100000,
    PartC: 150000,
};

const SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_RANGE = 1000;

let fleetData = [];

function populateFleetDropdown() {
    fleetData.forEach((fleet) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = fleet.fleetNumber;
        option.textContent = fleet.fleetNumber;
        fleetSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
    console.log("Dropdown options populated:", fleetSelect);
}

function updateVehicleDetails(selectedFleetNumber) {
    console.log("Selected fleet number:", selectedFleetNumber);

    const selectedFleet = fleetData.find(
        (fleet) => fleet.fleetNumber === selectedFleetNumber
    );

    if (selectedFleet) {
        console.log("Selected fleet:", selectedFleet);
        const vehicles = selectedFleet.vehicles;
        vehicleInfo.innerHTML = "";

        vehicles.forEach((vehicle) => {
            const vehicleDetails = document.createElement("div");
            vehicleDetails.className = "vehicle";
            vehicleDetails.innerHTML = `
                <h3>VIN: ${vehicle.vin}</h3>
                <p>Make: ${vehicle.make}</p>
                <p>Model: ${vehicle.model}</p>
                <p>KM's: ${vehicle.km}</p>
                <label for="kmInput-${vehicle.vin}">Update KM's:</label>
                <input type="number" id="kmInput-${vehicle.vin}" data-vin="${vehicle.vin}" min="${vehicle.km + 1}">
                <button class="update-km-btn" data-vin="${vehicle.vin}">Update</button>
            `;

            vehicleInfo.appendChild(vehicleDetails);
        });

        const updateButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".update-km-btn");
        updateButtons.forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener("click", updateKilometers);
        });
    } else {
        vehicleInfo.innerHTML = "<p>No vehicle data available.</p>";
    }
    console.log("Vehicle details updated.");
}

function checkPartReplacementNotifications(km) {
    Object.keys(PART_REPLACEMENT_INTERVALS).forEach((partName) => {
        const replacementInterval = PART_REPLACEMENT_INTERVALS[partName];
        const distanceToReplacement = replacementInterval - km;

        if (distanceToReplacement <= SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_RANGE && distanceToReplacement >= -5000) {
            if (distanceToReplacement <= 0) {
                const message = `Part ${partName} may need replacement soon.`;
                displayNotification(message);
            } else {
                const message = `Part ${partName} recommended to be replaced in ${distanceToReplacement} KM's.`;
                displayNotification(message);
            }
        }
    });
}

function checkServiceDueNotifications(km) {
    Object.keys(SERVICE_INTERVALS).forEach((serviceType) => {
        SERVICE_INTERVALS[serviceType].forEach((serviceInterval) => {
            const distanceToService = Math.abs(serviceInterval - km);

            if (distanceToService <= SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_RANGE) {
                const message = `${serviceType} Service is due in ${distanceToService} KM's.`;
                displayNotification(message);
            }
        });
    });

    checkPartReplacementNotifications(km);
}

function displayNotification(message) {
    const notificationItem = document.createElement("li");
    notificationItem.innerHTML = `
        <span>${message}</span>
        <button class="notification-dismiss">✓</button>
    `;
    notificationList.appendChild(notificationItem);

    const dismissButton = notificationItem.querySelector(".notification-dismiss");
    dismissButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        notificationList.removeChild(notificationItem);
    });
    console.log("Notification displayed:", message);
}

function updateKilometers(event) {
    const vin = event.target.getAttribute("data-vin");
    const kmInput = document.querySelector(`input[data-vin="${vin}"]`);

    const newKm = parseInt(kmInput.value);
    if (isNaN(newKm) || newKm <= parseInt(kmInput.getAttribute("min"))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid KM's value greater than the current value.");
        return;
    }

    const selectedFleet = fleetData.find(
        (fleet) => fleet.fleetNumber === fleetSelect.value
    );

    if (selectedFleet) {
        selectedFleet.vehicles.forEach((vehicle) => {
            if (vehicle.vin === vin) {
                vehicle.km = newKm;
                kmInput.setAttribute("min", newKm + 1);
                kmInput.value = "";
                checkServiceDueNotifications(vehicle.km);
                updateVehicleDetails(fleetSelect.value);
                updateOnlineData();
            }
        });
    }
}

function updateOnlineData() {
    const fleetRef = database.ref("fleetData");
    fleetRef.set(fleetData);
    console.log("Fleet data updated online:", fleetData);
}

function loadFleetDataFromFirebase() {
    const fleetRef = database.ref("fleetData");
    fleetRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
        const loadedData = snapshot.val();
        if (loadedData) {
            fleetData.length = 0;
            fleetData.push(...loadedData);
            console.log("Fleet data loaded from Firebase:", fleetData);
        }
    });
}
function attachFleetSelectListener() {
    fleetSelect.addEventListener("change", () => {
        const selectedFleetNumber = fleetSelect.value;
        updateVehicleDetails(selectedFleetNumber);
    });
}

function init() {
    console.log("Initializing app...");
    populateFleetDropdown();
    attachFleetSelectListener();
    loadFleetDataFromFirebase();
}

init();


init();
```

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.fleet-dropdown select {
    width: 100%; /* Adjust the width to 100% to fill the parent container */
    height: 40px; /* Increase the height as needed */
    padding: 6px; /* Add padding for better appearance */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border to indicate the dropdown */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Add border radius for rounded corners */
    font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size for better readability */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in the width calculation */
    background-color: white; /* Set background color to white */
}

/* Rest of your styles... */
```

I tried changing almost everything from data from the firebase to CSS and JS code